# Azure pipeline error: The type or namespace name 'Azure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline in azure devops but getting the error below.

> The type or namespace name 'Azure' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?

This error appears during my MSbuild task, the previous Nuget restore task works fine.

This is my project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{01511C7D-0BB5-4EF9-9B86-FE2B7B1E73DB}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>GraphSDK</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>GraphSDK</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="GraphClient.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Samples\Assignment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Samples\Submission.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity">
      <Version>1.5.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph">
      <Version>4.7.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

And this is my [MSbuild task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfihu.png), any idea what is the reason of the error or probably something related to my project?

BTW, it builds fine locally in VS2019.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: yes, it worked at the end. I put my solution as an aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How Did I solve it?

It seems there is a difference on how your project takes the nuget packages.

I had added them from Solution level, I mean.

1. Right click on the solution.
2. Manage Nuget Packages for Solution...

What worked was to remove the Nuget packages and add back but from Project level (I have 3 projects in my solution).

1. Right click on the project.
2. Manage Nuget Packages..
3. And install back all your packages (project by project).

Not sure why but it worked!!

Comment: The typical thing I've encountered in the .csproj file, the path shown on the Import or Error condition statement for the reference begins with "..\" and that re-installing removes the syntax.  For me, this seems to exist for references that have been part of the project for years.  i.e.:  `<Import Project="..\packages\  or <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the HintPath was incorrect - I had two separate A.sln and B.sln files referencing the same common.csproj common code.

To fix, I updated the HintPath in common.csproj since I was doing Nuget restore for A.sln but the HintPath was pointing to B.sln's \packages\ folder.

This likely would have had the same effect as if I removed and re-added the package to A.sln (and as the answer above), since all it would likely do is update HintPath.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I'm working with two projects, namely **ProjectOne.sln** and **ProjectTwo.sln**, which share **ProjectCommon.csproj**.
The problem is due to some packages having the `<HintPath>` referenced as `..\packages\`. Since this is a shared path, I addressed the issue by modifying it from `..\packages\` to `$(SolutionDir)\packages\`, which successfully resolved the problem.

Adding screenshot for reference:

> [image: SolutionDir change]